# How to stop ArcGIS Desktop automatically creating mapped drives?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, mxd

I have a MXD which I am using to make a PMF. I'm using ArcMap 10.1. I want my layers only to have UNC paths (starting with \\server...) as otherwise some users will get broken links if we have inconsistent mapped drives. Unfortunately, sometimes ArcMap 10.1 switches some layers to my mapped drive equivalent of the file path. I don't know why. When I try to change them all back to UNC paths in a wholesale fashion by disconnecting the relevant mapped drive so I can then switch one layer to the UNC path and let that propogate through all, ArcMap 10.1 decides instead to re establish the relevant mapped drive when starting up.

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: now it has mysteriously decided to swap them all back to UNC paths. there must be a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Arc Catalog, make sure you have a Folder Connection to the UNC path. It is possible to have multiple connections to the same data, e.g via a mapped drive and a UNC connection to the same geoDB or shapefile.

When adding data to a map in Arc Map, make sure you're navigating through the UNC path to the data. I don't ever recall Arc Map substituting a mapped drive if you added the data via UNC.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also have never seen ArcMap doing such a thing. It seems to just switch everything over every now and again, and I think it's when I add a layer from a mapped drive which comes from, effectively, the same location as other layers which are referred to via UNC paths. Nevertheless, this problem exists of ArcMap recreating a mapped drive which is referred to in a MXD. It is a pain as it was a really efficient way to re establish connections to everything via UNC paths. I could check on someone else's computer. Maybe it just does this on the computer with which the MXD was made.